# "will be exploring" or "will have explored"

Tags: future

I have a question about the future continuous and the future perfect. In this sentence:
Probably by the time you read this I will have unpacked, and I ________ the town before it gets too dark.
Is it correct to write "will be exploring"? Or is it "will have explored"?
Thank you :D

Comment: Both are correct - depending on whether you will still be exploring the town or have finished exploring the town.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are almost equivalent. Let's try and understand the difference between the two.

**Future Continuous** (will be exploring): Used when a prolonged action is disturbed by a shorter one.

> I will be sleeping when she arrives home from work tomorrow.
>
> I will be exploring the town before it gets too dark. (exploring interrupted by dark)

**Future Perfect**(will have explored): Used when a certain activity will be done by a particular time in future.

> I will have finished with assignment in an hour.
>
> I will have explored the town before it gets too dark.

Later suggests that you will be done with exploring the town before it gets dark. Unless you are really sure of completing the activity in time, I would suggest to go with former.